# What does Input Size column in web UI indicate?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What does input size of a batch in spark streaming indicate?
Does it indicate the count of lines in the batch or something else?
I read the stream from Kafka.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The input size represents the number of datasets/JSON received from the Kafka for processing for that particular time period.

It also depends on the data type you are processing. As you see in this image:

[image],

it is the number of datasets that has been received/read from Kafka queue for the mentioned period of time.

Here the micro batches are for scheduled for a period of 15 seconds.